# Schema hasn't been registered for model "Genre". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

making sense of this err message.

Schema hasn't been registered for model "Genre". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
thrown me as I'm not seeing a call for Genre, it is loading the model Book

### details below.

this is while working through the mdn tutorial > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data

my current repo > https://github.com/aspiringguru/mdn_express_nodejs_skeleton/tree/c347992765fadebe7af233c0f03ef222cbf4803f

the err is on this route in catalog.js
router.get('/book/:id', book_controller.book_detail);

https://github.com/aspiringguru/mdn_express_nodejs_skeleton/blob/c347992765fadebe7af233c0f03ef222cbf4803f/routes/catalog.js

to exports.book_detail in bookController.js

https://github.com/aspiringguru/mdn_express_nodejs_skeleton/blob/c347992765fadebe7af233c0f03ef222cbf4803f/controllers/bookController.js

The error appears to be in this code section

```
async.parallel({
    book: function(callback) {

        Book.findById(req.params.id)
          .populate('author')
          .populate('genre')
          .exec(callback);
    },
    book_instance: function(callback) {
      BookInstance.find({ 'book': req.params.id })
      .exec(callback);
    },
}, function(err, results) {
     console.log("exports.book_detail : function(err, results) ")
```

but I'm not seeing the error message just above

console error messages below.

exports.book_detail start                                                                                                                          exports.book_detail : function(err, results)                                                                                                       exports.book_detail : error : MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Genre".                                                 Use mongoose.model(name, schema)                                                                                                                   app.use(function...)                                                                                                                               err.message=Schema hasn't been registered for model "Genre".                                                                                       Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

the 'err.message=' is in app.py line line 62.

I've seen other stackoverflow/stachexchange questions where solutions move the mongoose.connect above the model imports, that did not work for me.

the part that is really confusing me is why the error is for 
Schema hasn't been registered for model "Genre"
I would have expected for model Book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the name of the `Genre` model is actually named [`GenreInstance`](https://github.com/aspiringguru/mdn_express_nodejs_skeleton/blob/master/models/genre.js#L19), not `Genre`.

Calling the endpoint will result in the app attempting to populate documents based on a model named `Genre` which doesn't exist, so Mongoose throws an error saying it can't find a Schema for that model.

Renaming the model to 'Genre' should fix it:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', GenreSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks, just worked this out today. Now it's obvious.